# Cannot access rstudio server after installation

Tags: server, rstudio

I am setting up a Linux server running Ubuntu and I want it to run rstudio server. In a previous server that I set up after install r-base and rstudio server, I could open a webpage and go the servers IP:8787 and I could use rstudio. Now for some reason the when I attempt to do this the internet page errors and says it cannot connect to the server.

I don't have a lot of experience with this type of programming and have no idea how to fix the problem. After several google searches, I have made sure my firewall will allow the connection (ufw allow 22 and ufw allow 8787) but this does not help.

R works on the command line and when I plug the server into a monitor I can access rstudio locally, but not remotely.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: From where are you trying to access it (same LAN? public internet?). Have you verified that the service is listening on the indicated port e.g. with `sudo netstat -nlp | grep :8787` or its `ss` equivalent?

Comment: @steeldriver When I run `sudo netstat -nlp | grep :8787` it returns.                            `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      979/rserver` I am using the same LAN. I can access the server on the command line, and R works in the terminal.

Comment: The `127.0.0.1` suggests it's only listening on the loopback interface: you'll either need to set up an SSH tunnel, or configure the `www-address` to bind to `0.0.0.0` as described here [RStudio Server: Configuring the Server](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552316-Configuring-the-Server)